# Float interferes with breakable tcolorbox

Tags: floats, tcolorbox

Today I noticed, that a breakable `tcolorbox` can be interrupted by a floating object, e.g. a figure. IMHO this is rather strange and shouldn't happen. Thus I wonder, how I can force the floating object to (automatically) respect the boxes' structure, i.e. to output the float before or after the `tcolorbox` only, but never in between.

Are there any ideas? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{breakable}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]
\begin{figure}
\caption{Test}
\blindtext[3]
\end{figure}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Ein interessanter Ausflug]
Test
\begin{verbatim}
sdfsdfsdfsd

sdfsf
\end{verbatim}

sdfsdf
\begin{verbatim}
sdfsdfsdfsd

sdfsf
\end{verbatim}
Test
\begin{verbatim}
sdfsdfsdfsd

sdfsf
\end{verbatim}
Test
\begin{verbatim}
sdfsdfsdfsd

sdfsf
\end{verbatim}
Test
\begin{verbatim}
sdfsdfsdfsd

sdfsf
\end{verbatim}
Test
\begin{verbatim}
sdfsdfsdfsd

sdfsf
\end{verbatim}
Test
\begin{verbatim}
sdfsdfsdfsd

sdfsf
\end{verbatim}
Test
\begin{verbatim}
sdfsdfsdfsd

sdfsf
\end{verbatim}
Test
\begin{verbatim}
sdfsdfsdfsd

sdfsf
\end{verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\begin{figure}[htb]` and see the magic.

Comment: latex can only place floats in the h,t,b,p positions so it can never place it after the end of a split box. It could (perhaps) prevent top floats on pages that have a split box, but the float would then have to go to the bottom of that page, or the next page.

Comment: @HarishKumar using `h` so it doesn't float will only work sometimes of course:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What Harish suggests is avoiding `p` option which is the option selected in the example. Without it, the figure appears after the whole tcolorbox.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It works for the given code ;-) And floats are floats and one needs to do hard work some times :-)

Comment: Why strange? One canot make breakable and unbreakable  and floating but static boxes at the same time. You can not fly and swim at the same time, unless you're a penguin.

Comment: @Fran Well, a split box remains one object, so a normal user naturally expects nothing in between.

Comment: @Ignasi Thank you very much. "p" is indeed what I will remove. I still have to check, whether it works everywhere in "real" examples.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your answer. I get your point. However, I understand, that it is not clear to every user.

Comment: @Martin, IHMO, just the opposite. Exactly the problem  is that a [broken box](https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3218/2735960331_1623286cb8.jpg)  is no longer one box. This allow the page break  but also give a chance to the floats.